# How to restore flash memory missed space?

Tags: partitioning, diskpart

My flash memory is 16 GB but windows reads it as 4 MB. I tried to use diskpart but it still says 4 MB. I also tried to see if there is any unallocated memory space but i did not find anything. I don't know what the problem is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get hands on a linux (maybe live) system?

Answer (score 0):

Your flash memory is probably broken, it seems to report the wrong size. If it was just a problem with the partition table, diskpart would report the full size.

Comment: I have just used it to move some data and when i opened it on another PC i found that problem. Does this PC broke it??

Comment: That's impossible to know.